# Pass data from PFQueryTableView to UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, parse-platform, tableview

I have been trying to do this now for a couple of days with no luck! Heres a rundown of what my app does. The user is presented with a view controller, they will type in a web address and click save. When the user clicks save they will be sent to a PFQueryTableView. When the user taps on a cell they are taken to a web view where they will see the website they input in the beginning of the app. I am storing all of the users input in a parse backend. I know I have to pass the data using a segue, but I have tried everything!

Here is my code for reference:

PFQueryTableView.h:

```
@interface MenuTableViewController : PFQueryTableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) PFObject *selectLink;

@end
```

PFQueryTableView.m:

```
@interface MenuTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation MenuTableViewController
@synthesize selectLink;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
        // Use this classname to query
        self.parseClassName = @"Referrals";

        // The key value shows in lable on cell
        self.textKey = @"RefLink";

        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    if (currentUser) {
        NSLog(@"Current user: %@", currentUser.username);

    }
    else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];

    }

    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = NO;
    //[self loadObjects];


    //Changes nav bar title color
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor grayColor]}];

    //changes nav bar color
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:102.0/255.0 green:204.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1]];

    //changes nav bar butto colors
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    //Changes transparency of nav bar
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;

}

#pragma mark - Reload Data
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([PFUser currentUser])
        [self loadObjects];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
}

// load data objects from backend
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {

    // Create a query
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

    // Follow relationship
    if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
        [query whereKey:@"author" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    }
    else {
        // I added this so that when there is no currentUser, the query will not return any data
        // Without this, when a user signs up and is logged in automatically, they briefly see a table with data
        // before loadObjects is called and the table is refreshed.
        // There are other ways to get an empty query, of course. With the below, I know that there
        // is no such column with the value in the database.
        [query whereKey:@"nonexistent" equalTo:@"doesn't exist"];
    }

    return query;
}


#pragma mark - Cell Structure
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"refCell";

    PFTableViewCell *cell = (PFTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    // Configure the cell

    //Links lables to backend
    UILabel *refLink = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
    refLink.text = [object objectForKey:@"RefLink"];


    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Delete Data From Table
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            [self loadObjects];
        }];
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"We were unable to delete the selected row :(" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alertView show];
    }
}

#pragma mark - LogOut
- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender {
    [PFUser logOut];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
}

#pragma mark - Segue
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"editSegue"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        WebViewController *data = (WebViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        data.webAddress = object;



    }
}

@end
```

WebView.h:

```
@interface WebViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) PFObject *webAddress;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *webLink;

@end
```

WebView.m:

```
@interface WebViewController ()

@end

@implementation WebViewController
@synthesize webView,webAddress,webLink;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.



    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webAddress];
    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];



}

@end
```

If someone could help me pass the data from the table view to the web view and have the website display in the web view I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You don't actually say what doesn't work. This bit `[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webAddress]` is wrong because the address isn't a URL...

Comment: When I press on the TableViewCell the website never loads.

Comment: Too broad. Are the methods called? Which ones? How far does it get?

Comment: I am new to this, and I have uploaded majority of my code. I apologize if this question is too broad for you. I just want to know how to grab the data from the table view cell, and have the data appear on the web view.

Comment: You need to learn abut breakpoints / logging to debug. You need to find out how far it gets and therefore when it fails. Otherwise you're asking someone to read and analyse every line of code you have in the hope of finding the problem, which is time consuming. I've already pointed out one error but you need to help us to help you.